# jQuery click event not working on option element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
$('select option').live('click', function(){
  alert('hello')
})
```

html:

```
<select class="ok">
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/fQxj7/2/

Comment: Your example fiddle works fine for me... I'm using Firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.04. What are you using?

Comment: While FishBasketGordo's approach works, this still begs the question as to why yours doesn't. It works on FF and "click" is a valid event for <option>.

Comment: @Spycho - yes it worked with Firefox 5 to top, but not work for Chrome.!!!!!!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

If you need to know the selected value inside the event handler, then you can do this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/2ABAh/

Comment: That's a much better approach, but it doesn't explain why the OP's present solution doesn't work. Does their fiddle work for you? It does for me...

Comment: I don't believe that click events get fired for `<option>` tags across all browsers.

Comment: I agree, but I believe it is supposed to.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it's not supposed to in HTML 4.01 (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION), but it is in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html).

Comment: please give me example wit HTML5?

Comment: I'm 99% sure my example will still work with HTML5, but I haven't tested it.