# dropdown: two type of events can't bind of jquery in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

their is some problem of click event in chrome

```
<select id="id-name" name="name-her">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1" class="verify">Verify</option>
        <option value="2" class="delete">Reject</option>
</select>

$('.verify').bind("click", function( evt ){
    alert('clicked');
});

$('.delete').bind("click", function( evt ){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

here we want to initiate two events on the basis of class which one is clicked, It works fine in firefox but not in chrome.

Any 
suggestion please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click event not working on option element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080213/jquery-click-event-not-working-on-option-element)

Comment: @John: yeah solved now it was because of class should be on select tag :) wondering for multiple events!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id=”category”>
   <option value=”3″ onclick=”getOption(3);”>Option1</option>
</select>
```

This works fine in Firefox, i.e. the function ‘getCategories’ gets called when choosing an object in the select box. This does not work for the other browsers though, the calls are not made and there are even no errors raised.

The solution is to make the function call on the select-tag instead using the onchange-event referencing the value of the select tag (which will hold the value of the chosen option-tag),

```
<select id="category" onchange="getOption($('category').val());">
   <option value="3">Option1</option>
</select>
```