# Why this handler doesnt works on Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/cSBET/) :

```
<select id="example">
    <option value="38">Marco</option>
    <option value="39">Hello</option>
</select>​

$("#example> option").click(function () {
    alert("ciao");
});
```

clicking on a drop down item, the alert is not showed... IE and Firefox no problems..

Comment: Bind the click event to the select box to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/cSBET/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080213/jquery-click-event-not-working-on-option-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('#example').change(...)` - selecting/clicking an element will change the value of the selectbox so that should work.

Comment: Clicking on same selected option will not trigger `change` event.

Answer (score 1):

Use the change function instead - it is perfectly suited for drop-downs.

```
$('#example').change(function() {
    alert('ciao');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems as though `.change()` is the correct way to go about this on the `<select>` element.

note, though, that you'll have to retrieve the option manually once a change event has been fired on the `<select>` since `this` refers to a `<select>` element and not an `<option>` element.

you'll have to do this: `var $selected = $(this).find(":selected");`

`$selected` will contain the select option, or multiple selected options if multiple select is enabled.

just want to clarify that `.change()` is to be used on the `<select>` element and not the `<option>` elements.