# How do I assign my select option to another variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to keep track of what option I have selected 1 thru 5.  I can't use the value option as I use that to store the image. So I count the number of options.  The code below works great in Firefox, but seems like the script doesn't run under Chrome or Safari.  Have not tried IE or edge yet.  Any Ideas please?  Example at:  http://rtpcservices.com/count_options.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<span>Click a option!</span>

<select id="selected_image" name="selected_image" onchange="
$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

<?php
echo '
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_1 . ' ">Image 1</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_2 . ' ">Image 2</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_3 . ' ">Image 3</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_4 . ' ">Image 4</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_5 . ' ">Image 5</option>
</select>
';
?>

<script>
$( "option" ).click(function() {
    // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
    var index = $( "option" ).index( this );
    $( "span" ).text( "Image Selected_option #" + (index+1));
    document.getElementById("selected_option").value = index;    
});

</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand, why you need to bind 'click' on option as you can handle it 'onchange' event. `onchange` must be bind with a function where you can store your selected option.

Comment: look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080213/jquery-click-event-not-working-on-option-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a change event

```
$( "#selected_image" ).change(function() {
    var index = $( "option:selected" ).index();
    $( "span" ).text( "Image Selected_option #" + (index+1));
    $("#selected_option").val(index);
});
```

```js
$( "#selected_image" ).change(function() {
    var index = $( "option:selected" ).index();
    $( "span" ).text( "Image Selected_option #" + (index+1));
    $("#selected_option").val(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selected_image" name="selected_image">
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_1 . ' ">Image 1</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_2 . ' ">Image 2</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_3 . ' ">Image 3</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_4 . ' ">Image 4</option>
    <option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_5 . ' ">Image 5</option>
</select>
<span></span>
<input type="text" id="selected_option">
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick.  At first it still didn't work so I ran your code snippet, then viewed source.  I found I was missing     <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script> in the header.  Once I added, it all came to life.  Thanks guys

Comment: Dumb question, how do I say you answered my question so you get a green check mark?

Comment: under the voting number you have a check, you click that :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Oh my gosh, I really am not that stupid.  I looked every where but didn't do that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following code
try to change the following line

```
var index = $( "option" ).index( this );
```

to

```
var index = $( "option:selected" ).index( this );
```

Comment: what is `.index( this )` suppose to mean?